# Jquery for CSS attribute change with ease and return on place again

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am trying to open left slidepanel here is the code

```
jQuery('.right_panel_handle').on('click',function() {
    jQuery('.right_panel').css({'right':'0px'});
    return false;
});
```

I am trying to change position on click with ease and upon click again it should return to its place.

Need help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('.right_panel_handle').on('click',function() {
    var panel = jQuery('.right_panel');
    if (panel.offset().left > $(window).width() - panel.width()){
        panel.css('right', '0px');
    } else {
        panel.css('right', - panel.width() + 'px');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,

Code above (mine) is opening the panel in an instance, I need to add some easing in it. 2nd code above is not closing the panel.

Your code make me confused as this is not working and not taking -ve value. 

Value should be 0 for open and -272px for close.

Comment: it`s hard to fix it without jsfiddle. anyway i didnt recommend to you using jquery animations for it. use class like '.expland', style it with css transition, and toggleClass on click. Its mych cleaner and faster

Comment: Here is the link of jsfiddle


https://jsfiddle.net/Dr_Morpheus/wmjzgts8/2/

Comment: and thats what i talking about css animation styling, its cleaner and smooth: https://jsfiddle.net/artemfs/wmjzgts8/6/